# Find indices of where Pandas Series contains element containing character

Tags: python, string, pandas, contains, series

Example:

```
import pandas as pd    
arr = pd.Series(['a',['a','b'],'c'])
```

I would like to get the indices of where the series contains elements containing `'a'`. So I would like to get back indices `0` and `1`.

I've tried writing

```
arr.str.contains('a')
```

but this returns

```
0     True
1      NaN
2    False
dtype: object
```

while I'd like it to return

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: object
```

Comment: Do you want `True` if value in `arr` is `ate`?  `'a' in 'ate'` evaluates to `True` but `'a' in ['ate']` evaluates to `False`.  Depending on what you want, the provided answers may not be appropriate.

Comment: @piRSquared, good point! Let's wait for a clarification...

Comment: @MaxU's answer was able to solve my problem - thanks for the rapid response! (Just to clarify: I wanted to retrieve any instance containing the letter 'a', including 'ate')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [Series.str.join()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) to concatenate lists/arrays in cells into a single string and then use `.str.contains('a')`:

```
In [78]: arr.str.join(sep='~').str.contains('a')
Out[78]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Nice answer here!

Comment: See my comment on OP... I see ambiguity in the question.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

### Use `Series.apply` and Python's `in` keyword which works on both lists and strings

```
arr.apply(lambda x: 'a' in x)
```

This will work fine if you don't have any NaN values in your `Series`, but if you do, you can use:

```
arr.apply(lambda x: 'a' in x if x is not np.nan else x)
```

This is much faster than using `Series.str`.

### Benchmarks:

```
%%timeit
arr.str.join(sep='~').str.contains('a')
```

Takes: `249 µs ± 4.83 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

```
%%timeit
arr.apply(lambda x: 'a' in x)
```

Takes: `70.1 µs ± 1.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`

```
%%timeit
arr.apply(lambda x: 'a' in x if x is not np.nan else x)
```

Takes: `69 µs ± 1.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`

Comment: `%timeit pd.Series(['a' in cell for cell in arr], index=arr.index)` will be even faster ;-)

Comment: Haha, absolutely!